# Android layout editor "missing classes"

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I'm using Android Studio Artic Fox, and I create a descendant of ConstraintLayout...

I get a layout editor as follow:

[image: Android Studio screenshot showing layout editor]
As you can see, there's an error message about "Missing classes". Now when I use my descendant class in another layout, I get that message again and nothing renders, which is pretty annoying. I've found some older questions with similar (but different) issues, and wondered if anyone had bumped into that one.

Edit: per request, here's sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testing.TestConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</testing.TestConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should show your XML. Is the class name fully qualified in the layout?

Comment: Added XML. Yes, class name is fully qualified, and Ctrl+Click it brings me to the file, so it looks like Android Studio can find it.

Comment: What you posted works. Clean the project (Build->Clean Project) and invalidate caches (File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...) to see if that clears things up.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't do the File -> Invalidate Cache... will do.

Comment: Now have done it, didn't fix the issue... Since it's working for you, problem must lie somewhere else. Thanks!